# How do I run "yum -y update" from Bash Script?

Tags: linux, bash

When I try to run "yum -y update" from a Bash script it doesn't work.

Here is what the script looks like.

```
#!/usr/bin/
echo "--> Updating CentOS System"
yum -y update
```

I run the script with this command.

```
bash script.sh
```

I get the following output.

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
. Please use /usr/bin/yum --help.
```

CentOS 6 FINAL 
Installed via text prompts.
I login as root from the text prompt then startx to get into the gui desktop.

But when I run the same command directly in the terminal it works?

I've googled around but not sure if I'm googling the correct terms.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: chmod u+x script.sh give permission n try or you may run these commands as root user.

Comment: Your hashbang (`!#/usr/bin/`) is incorrect--it should be something like `#!/usr/bin/bash`--, but is not relevant to your error since you explicitly run the script with `bash`.

Comment: @chepner - Made the change. Getting a weird "Unexpected token" error but the code looks correct.  If I run the same script with the bash command it acctualy starts the script without any error.  But YUM commands don't seem to work.

Comment: @Shailesh - Made the changes requested still have issue.

Comment: #! /bin/bash put this line in your script and remove !#/usr/bin/

Answer (score 7):

Not sure why your script does not work, but my version worked fine.  (I suspect it might be the first line):

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "--> Updating CentOS System"
yum -y update
```

Remember to chmod 755 the file, and you can just run it with the file name, no need to prepend it with "bash".

I do note that when I tried to reproduce your problem I couldn't (even though your first line is incorrect the script still worked for me).  I wonder if there might have been a hidden typo in the key shell line ?  Maybe try deleting it and re-adding it.

Comment: Did above still seem to be having an issue.  Made the change as well.   Not sure what's going on here.  I'll keep you posted.  Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Change `#!/usr/bin/` to `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).